# how to open a new tab with Mink and Behat?

Tags: selenium, behat, mink

i need to write a test for an email validation.
i would like to open a new tab to go to my webmail, is it possible with behat, mink and selenium2driver? i saw switchToWindow() function, but how to switch if there is only one window?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to open specifically new tabs, but you can use a different session, which should open a different window. Define sessions in your `behat.yml`:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            sessions:
                first_session:
                    selenium2: ~
                second_session:
                    goutte: ~
                third_session:
                    selenium2: ~
```

And then switch the session in a step definition with:

```
$this->getMink()–>setDefaultSessionName('third_session');
```

The config example is for Behat 3. Read more about the concept [here](http://swdesigns.co.uk/2012/07/multiple-sessions-with-behat-mink-and-selenium2/), it might be slightly outdated though.